# How to replace string in python string with specific character?

Tags: python, pandas

for example, I have a column named `Children` in data frame of python,

few names are `[ tom (peter)  , lily, fread, gregson (jaeson 123)]`  etc.

I want to ask that what code I should write, that could remove part of each name staring with bracket e.g '(' and so on. So that from my given names example tom(peter) will become tom in my column and gregson (123) would become gregson.  Since there are thousands of names with bracket part and I want to remove the part of string staring from bracket '(' and ending on bracket ')'.  This is a data frame of many columns but i want to do this editing in one specific column named as CHILDREN  in my dataframe named DF.

Comment: Are you talking about the pandas module ? You say you have a dataframe, i think this type is only in pandas module

Comment: try pandas.Series.str.replace with regex

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Ruslan S., you can use `pandas.Series.str.replace` or you could also use `re.sub` (and there are other methods as well):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["tom (peter)" , "lily", "fread", "gregson (jaeson 123)"]})
# OPTION 1 with str.replace :
df["name"] = df["name"].str.replace(r"\([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\)", "").str.strip()
```

```
# OPTION 2 :with re sub
import re
r = re.compile(r"\([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\)")
df["name"] = df["name"].apply(lambda x: r.sub("", x).strip())
```

And the result in both cases:

```
      name
0      tom
1     lily
2    fread
3  gregson
```

Note that I also use strip to remove leading and trailing whitespaces here. For more info on the regular expression to use, see `re` [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
#to remove text between () 
df['columnname'] = df['columnname'].str.replace(r'\((.*)\)', '')
#to remove text between %%
df['columnname'] = df['columnname'].str.replace(r'%(.*)%', '')
```

Comment: Thanks, would you please explain concept, working of this piece of code. so that i could use it for other things also. E.g  to change  tom %45%  to  tom  i.e in case if '%' is used instead of bracket

Comment: r'\((.*)\)' is regular expression meaning everything between' (' and ')'  for %45% you have to r'%(.*)%'